# Proof that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$ is unbounded without setting $x=y^3$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$ is unbounded. I am aware that the most straightforward method is to choose $(x,y)$ such that $x=y^3$. However, I have attempted an alternative proof. Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $M \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$ (the case in which $M=0$ is trivial). Set $y:=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$. Thus, for any $x$ $\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, we have that $x>y^2$, and so that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$. We now argue that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}>M$.

Note that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ is monotonically increasing as $x \rightarrow 0$. Also, note that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{2}{x}$. Thus, as $x \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ becomes arbitrarily large (as the upper bound towards which it is monotonically increasing becomes arbitrarily large). Thus, there must exist an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>M$, for $(x,y):=(x, \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}})$.

Comment: Note that you already set $x=2y^2$

Comment: @Andrei hence I wrote ‘without’ in the title. Additionally, does my proof work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see any obvious errors. But it looks very convoluted. The way I approach this problems is using polar coordinates. $x=r\cos\theta$, $y^3=r\sin\theta$. Then you have
$$\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^3}=\frac{r\cos\theta\cdot r^{2/3}\sin^{2/3}\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}\propto r^{-1/3}$$
This last term diverges to $\infty$ around $(0,0)$ on many trajectories. You can choose any of them, as long as $\cos\theta\sin^{2/3}\theta$ does not go faster to zero than $r^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you say my post works as a proof of the proposition, or is it not sufficiently rigorous\clear?

Comment: @Charles It is confusing. Once you set $y$ as a function of $x$, replace it everywhere. Otherwise one does not know if the two variables can still be independent or do they obey the relationship you wanted.